# Client Validation is not working

Tags: validation, client

I am new to mvc. I have gone through the codes below but still the client validation is not working

In my web.config I have

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

In my Models I have

```
 namespace MvcValidation.Models
    {
        public class EmailAddress
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name="User ID")]
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "User Name1")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(20,MinimumLength=5)]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter Website")]
            public string Website { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Location { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string State { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string City { get; set; }
    }
    }

In Create.cshtml I have

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<h2>Create</h2>
<table>
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    { 
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.UserId)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.UserId)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserId)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.UserName)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.UserName)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserName)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Password)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Email)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Email)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Email)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Website)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Website)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Website)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Location)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Location)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Location)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.State)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.State)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.State)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.City)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.City)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.City)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And in HomeController I have

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }
        [ActionName("Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create_P(EmailAddress ed)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(ed);
        }
```

Please help me out so that I can use client validation

Answer (score 0):

If you started from empty MVC project you have to add Scripts and Optimisation framework via Nuget. Also make sure you have configured bundles correctly in Bundle config and add it in Application_Start() method. In your master layout render the scripts and add reference to jquery scripts. Finnaly add validation scripts to your partial view.